# Problems getting Django/Apache2/mod_wsgi configured without having extra component in URL

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have Apache serve all content at mysite.com/ and have Django handle everything under `mydomain.com/signup` and `mydomain.com/login`.

The problem is that right now the user has to browse to `mydomain.com/mysite/signup` or `mydomain.com/mysite/login` for things to work.  I want to get rid of the mysite part of the URLs.

I created a project with

```
django-admin startproject signup mysite
cd mysite
django-admin startapp login
```

I ended up with this directory structure.

```
mysite
├── login
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
└── signup
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

I have the following urlpatterns in signup/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^login/', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I have Apache mod_wsgi installed and working and have this WSGIScriptAlias in my virtual host file.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/mysite/signup/wsgi.py process-group=mysite.com
```

When the user goes to either `mydomain.com/mysite/signup` or `mydomain.com/mysite/login` everything works.

What I want to do is get rid of the `'mysite'` part of the above URLs so the user just has to browse to `mydomain.com/signup` or `mydomain.com/login`.

I've tried

```
WSGIScriptAlias /signup /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/mysite/signup/wsgi.py process-group=mysite.com
WSGIScriptAlias /login /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/mysite/signup/wsgi.py process-group=mysite.com
```

But that doesn't work because either Apache or mod_wsgi strips off the 'signup' or 'login' part before it gets to Django and Django just thinks the user is looking for '/'.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /signup /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/mysite/signup/wsgi.py/signup process-group=mysite.com application-group=%{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias /login /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/mysite/signup/wsgi.py/login process-group=mysite.com application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

Note how the mount point is added after `wsgi.py`. The `application-group` option is also added to ensure you only get one instance of your Django application in the process.

The other way is for any static files to be handled by Apache, with everything else handled by the WSGI application. How to do this is documented towards end of section 'The Apache Alias Directive' in:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#the-apache-alias-directive

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Worked like a charm. Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a prefix, don't use one.

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/www/....
```

Comment: I want / served by Apache

Comment: Then you want two contradictory things.

Comment: / with nothing else served by Apache, /signup and /login served by wsgi